# Fix Firefox throwing error on setInterval.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Why does  `setInterval(fetchData(), 1000*60);` work in Chrome while throw an error Firefox; I want to pass a variable into fetchdata.

```
   function fetchData(var) {
        .....
    };

    fetchData(var); //run once
    setInterval(fetchData(var), 1000*60); //then repeat
```

Stack Trace:

```
[10:26:49.764] Error: useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)
userController@http://localhost:8000/mainx.js:169
invoke@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:2809
instantiate@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:2819
@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:4639
applyDirectivesToNode/nodeLinkFn/<@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:4218
forEach@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:117
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:4203
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:3851
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:3763
bootstrap/</<@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:932
Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:7840
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:7920
bootstrap/<@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:930
invoke@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:2802
bootstrap@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:929
angularInit@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:904
@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular.js:14527
p.Callbacks/k@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
p.Callbacks/l.fireWith@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
.ready@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
D@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is incorrect. You can't pass variables like this using setTimeout or setInterval.

```
setInterval(fetchData(var), 1000*60); //then repeat
```

Use the following instead.

```
setInterval(function() {
    fetchData(var);
}, 1000*60);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
setInterval(function() {fetchData(var)}, 1000*60); //then repeat
```

What you are doing isn't actually passing your argument at all. You need to wrap it in an **[anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)**.